# How to attach several photos to a wall post?

Tags: facebook, attachment

If you go to this app's wall: http://www.facebook.com/mindjolt they somehow attach several photos to each wall post. Is there a way to do this programatically?

Looks like they are posting to the wall manually, but I can't even figure out how to do this through facebook interface.

Any ideas?

Comment: @ BlaXpirit: I would hate to see stackoverflow spread around in several more specific sites like webapps.stackexchange.com specially since you don't get to keep your points/profile when you sign up to a stackexchange site.  Edit: This was a response to someone else's comment. It's gone now :-S

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question attentively. I removed the comment. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options that I'm aware of:

You can use the Facebook Graph API to post to someone's wall. You can attach a picture (I'm pretty sure it's only one), link, video, etc. to the post: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post

Alternatively, you can use the stream.publish method from the old REST API http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish and set the attachment.media parameter http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments to post more than one image in one wall post.

Comment: It says on the stream attachement page: "You can include up to 5 photos in the media array. However, only one photo gets displayed in the Feed story; the user can see the remaining photos by clicking a "See More" link that gets appended to the story. Photos can be up to 90 pixels in both height and width.". It is not what that app has.

Answer (score 1):

I there no way to do it with the new Javascript API (SDK)?

The old way was:

```
var media = [];
media[0] = {'type':'image','src':'xxx','href':'yyy'};
media[1] = {'type':'image','src':'xxx','href':'yyy'};
media[2] = {'type':'image','src':'xxx','href':'yyy'};
media[3] = {'type':'image','src':'xxx','href':'yyy'};
media[4] = {'type':'image','src':'xxx','href':'yyy'};


 attachment = {
        'href':'xxx',
        'name':'xxx',
    'caption': '',
        'media': media
    };

FB.Connect.streamPublish('', attachment, '');
```

but the new way?

```
FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'feed',

            name: attachment.name,
            link: attachment.href,
            caption: attachment.caption,
            picture: 'xxx',
        }
        ,
        function(response) 
        {
            alert('callback');
    }
);
```

there is no key for attachment or for media, only picture??

edit: Ok, I got it, there is the old way, the new way, and there is the old way via the new way:

```
FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'stream.publish',

            attachment: attachment,
            action_links: action_link
        }
        ,
        function(response) 
        {
            //alert('callback');
        }
    );
```